# Twice as many elements in rep() using the same vector?

Tags: r, rep

I have to solve a question for a class where I have to create a vektor vek1 of length = 60 with twice as many "a" than "b" entries using rep().

My solution is:`
`x <- c("a", "a", "b")`
`vek1 <- rep(x,each = 1, length.out = 60)`

Is there a more beautiful and effective solution to solve the question?

Comment: No need of `each = 1`, you can remove that part.

Comment: There are many small variations. The effectiveness of each solution is pretty binary: it works or it doesn't. The beauty of each answer is mostly a matter of opinion, and I would say can't really be determined without a larger context. `rep(c("a", "b"), times = c(40, 20))`, `rep(c("a", "a", "b"), each = 20)`, `rep(c("a", "a", "b"), length.out = 60)` (your answer without the `each`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
rep(rep(c('a', 'b'), c(2, 1)), length.out=60)
```

This wouldn't probably be my first choice but what I like about this solution is that it uses exactly the information from your question: the two letters, their proportion and the vector length.

Answer (score 0):

Using indexing:

```
c("a", "b")[1:60%/%1.5%%2+1]
```

or, since indices are coerced to integers:

```
letters[40:99/40]
```

checking the answers:

```
table(c("a", "b")[1:60%/%1.5%%2+1])
#> 
#>  a  b 
#> 40 20
table(letters[40:99/40])
#> 
#>  a  b 
#> 40 20
```